# General rule to show limit exists , without from starting assuming it exists to show the limiting value

Tags: limits

We often when solving for limit problem assume that a given limit exist and finite without proving at first and then solve with techinques like taking natural log or sometimes raising it to e^(..) , we give the argument that if the limit value after solving (with limit exist assuming supposition) and get that its a finite value then we say that we showed our assumption is true . But is it possible to show limit exists from start ? And then evaluate it later onwards ? Like for example $limit_{x \rightarrow 0} ({x})^x$  = 1 ( without from starting assuming **limit exists and natural logarithm is continuous at that limiting value** )

Comment: You mean $ \lim_{x\to 0^+} x^x $, by the right.

Comment: "we give the argument that if the limit value after solving (with limit exist assuming supposition) and get that its a finite value then we say that we showed our assumption is true ." Not quite. We show that if the limit exists, it must have that value. We still need to verify that value actually is the limit.

Comment: We verify by epsilon delta method or some other approach @eyeballfrog ?

Comment: @hamam_Abdallah yeah right . May you show that from starting limit exists or its not possible to prove from starting at all ?

Comment: How can you compute $ x^x $ without speaking about exponential.

Comment: Taking logarithms or exponents in evaluations of limits is a technique which can be justified (but not usually done by textbook authors). So your concern is genuine. I have addressed this in my [blog post](https://paramanands.blogspot.com/2013/11/teach-yourself-limits-in-8-hours-part-3.html?m=0).

Comment: For your case the technique tries to evaluate the limit of $x\log x$ and using this information deduces the limit of $x^x$. The process does not assume existence of limit of $x^x$ or $x\log x$.

Comment: Yeah that what i was asking to in a different way @hamam_Abdallah

Comment: Thanks that blog post is amazing, it clearly explain it with proper reasoning thanks @ParamanandSingh

Answer (score 1):

You can show $\lim_{x\to 0^+} x^x$ exists by using [Monotone Convergence Theorem](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monotone_convergence_theorem). So show $x^x$ is decreasing for $0<x<1/e$ and that $x^x$ is bounded above (by 1).

Comment: How did you prove it is decreasing.

Comment: Find derivative for example.

Comment: And? OP asked how to show limit exists?

Comment: Sorry, you are right.